# Is there a service like AWS GameLift in Unity3D?

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine

We want to provide a Unity realtime multiplay gaming service by deploying a Dedicated server created with UNET.
It's able to use AWS EC2 or GameLift.

But apart from this, is there a service that can also deploy UNET Server to AutoScaling in Unity Services without another cloud services?